# Typescript X is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem with my code. I have no error when I compile my code, but I have a console error:  this.trackArray[0].points.getVector() is not a function.

Here is my code where I call this function

```
const vecteurPoints: THREE.Vector3[] = this.trackArray[0].points.getVector();
```

Here is the function

```
public getVector(): Vector3[] {
    const vecArray: Vector3[] = new Array();
    for (const i of this.coordX) {
        vecArray[i].x = this.coordX[i];
        vecArray[i].y = this.coordY[i];
        vecArray[i].z = this.coordZ[i];
    }

    return vecArray;
}
```

In VS Code, when I ctrl+click on the function it sends me to the function definition.

I get my trackArray with a call to an API.

```
export class AdminService {
    public constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {  }

    public getTracks(): Observable<Track[]> {
        return this.http.get<Track[]>(this.ADMIN_URL).pipe(catchError(this.handleError<Track[]>("getTracks"))
        );
 }
```

And I call this class like this

```
 this.admin.getTracks().subscribe((track: Track[]) => {this.trackArray = track; });
```

Comment: Have you verified that `this.trackArray[0]` exists?

Comment: Also, the `getVector()` function is problematic, because it tries to set properties on `vecArray[i]`, when `vecArray[i]` hasn't been created yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem! Because I got the trackArray with JSON, I had to instantiate a new track to apply my method! 
Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if **`this.trackArray`** does not contain elements. Add a null check

```
if(this.trackArray && this.trackArray[0]){
  const vecteurPoints: THREE.Vector3[] = this.trackArray[0].points.getVector();
}
```

Comment: If we know that trackArray is an array, and we know that each item in it has a `points` property, I think the only thing we should have to check is `if (this.trackArray[0])`

Comment: I used a console.log and the track have an element